# Images of Matrix not loading

Tags: matrix

First time working with matrix fields. In this case to load images. But somehow I can't manage to fetch the url of the Images. I can get the title and id but not the url. Can someone point me to the mistake am am making? Thanks!

```
{% set allProjects = craft.entries.section(['sectionHandle']) %} 

    {% for projects in allProjects.all() %} 

        {% for block in projects.matrixFieldHandle.all() %}

           {% if block.type == "image" %}

             {% set image = block.image.one() %}
             {% if image %}
              {{ image.url }}
             {% endif %}

           {% endif %}

       {% endfor %}

    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: If you view the source on the page, what gets output where you expect the image URL to be?

Comment: I can print {{ image.id }} ... title, width, height, but if I ask for {{ image.url }} there is nothing printed on screen or in the source. It's empty.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, when I load an url of a channel asset field.

Comment: Is it possible that it has to do with the fact, that the site runs on mamp?

Answer (score 2):

during this process : 
`{% set image = block.image.one() %}`
please make sure the name of handle of image is image. 
For example in this matrix the type is 'image' but to get image url you should call it. item.imageAssets.one().url
[image: Matrix]

Answer (score 1):

block.image is actually an array (even if only 1 image in it) therefore you need to loop over it so try this...

```
{% for image in block.image.all() %}{{ image.url }}{% endfor %}
```

If you want to check that there is an image first you can use this..

```
{% if block.image|length %} ... {% endif %}
```

Comment: Same result. I get an id of the image and the proper title, but it will not print the url.

Comment: Why do you need {% if block.type == "image" %} ? Have you defined the block.type as 'image'? try removing it.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking for |length

```
         {% if image|length %}
          {{ image.url }}
         {% endif %}
```

Comment: Still. Other parameters of the image are printed like id or title but not the url.